# DropDownListFor Form Submit not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a filter dropdownlistfor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedDateFilter, 
                      new SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, "id", "dt", Model.selectedDateFilter), 
                      "By Date", 
                      new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
```

When I change the selection I am getting nothing at all.

This is the page source:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        data-val="true" 
        data-val-number="The field selectedDateFilter must be a number."
        data-val-required="The selectedDateFilter field is required."
        id="selectedDateFilter" name="selectedDateFilter" 
        onchange="this.form.submit();"><option value="">By Date</option>
                                       <option value="1">April-2015</option>
                                       <option value="2">May-2015</option>
                                       <option value="3">June-2015</option>
                                       <option value="4">July-2015</option>
                                       <option value="5">August-2015</option>
                                       <option value="6">September-2015</option>
                                       <option value="7">October-2015</option>
                                       <option value="8">November-2015</option>
                                       <option value="9">December-2015</option>
                                       <option value="10">January-2016</option>
</select>
```

I noticed that all of the answers on this topic use a DropDownList and not a 'for'. Is there a reason for this? Why is the control not posting back?

EDIT: The model I am passing is an integer set to zero. Idea being that it will set the selecteditem by index after a post.

```
public int selectedDateFilter { get; set; }
selectedVenueFilter = 0;
```

This is where the error is creating the following in the source:

```
data-val="true" 
data-val-number="The field selectedDateFilter must be a number."

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedDateFilter, 
                      new SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, "id", "dt", Model.selectedDateFilter), 
                      "By Date", 
                      new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
```

I have checked the value of x.selectedDateFilter = 0. I also tried setting it to 1 and still the error.

Comment: Makes no difference if its `DropDownListFor()` or `DropDownList()` - the html generated is identical.

Comment: Do you have  form? Do you have an associated `ValidationMessageFor()`?

Comment: I do not have a validationmessagefor.

Comment: Your control is generating `data-val-` attributes for use by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` Could you model be invalid (therefore preventing the submit), but you don't know it because the messages are not displayed?

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer!!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, What is it you think you _mentioned in your answer_?. If your suggesting using `Model.selectedDateFilter` as the 4th parameter, then your not understanding model binding. The strongly typed helpers bind the the property value and the value `Model.selectedDateFilter` is completely ignored - its just pointless to include it.

Comment: I just noticed the SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, part of your answer Guruprasad. I retried with Dropdownlistfor and it worked.

Comment: No @StephenMuecke.. You misunderstood! I said I mentioned to change `onchange = "this.form.submit();` to `onchange = @"this.form.submit();` which the user has edited and said Solved using this!! I haven't noticed that he has changed from `DropDownListFor` to `DropDownList`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to do as below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedDateFilter, 
                      new SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, "id", "dt", Model.selectedDateFilter), 
                      "By Date", 
                      new { onchange = @"this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
```

You need to append `@` before `this.form.submit();`